# javascript click field

Tags: javascript

У меня есть похожий скрипт для социальной сети Вконтакте, но я пытался вписать в код класс, но ничего

Сам похожий скрипт

```
var counter_need = 100;
var timer = 10000;
(async () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < counter_need; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("friends_find_user_add")[i].click();
        await delay();
    }
    console.log("Готово!");
})();

function delay() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, timer);
    });
}
```

код элемента что нужно сделать[image]

Меня интересует класс friends_field_toggle_friend__add. Для добавления в друзья человека из списка друга.

Comment: добавьте код friends_find_user_add

Comment: думаю что там сам элемент поддерживает клик.  клиТут у вас у дочернего элемента есть клик

Comment: не понял вас, какой код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю это будет правильный вариант ответа

```
var timer = 10000;
(async () => {
    for(var item of document.querySelectorAll(".friends_field_toggle_friend__add a")) {
        item.click();
        await delay();
    }
    console.log("Готово!");
})();

function delay() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, timer);
    });
}
```